# JSF <h:outputFormat>: use array values as parameters

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2

On my JSF2 page, i'm using internationalized error messages.

In my backing bean, i'm putting the messages into the flash Scope:

```
flash.put("error", exception.getType());
```

On the page, this string gets translated this way:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bundle[flash.error]}"/>
```

Works fine.

NOW i want to be also able to put (an arbitrary number of) parameters into the message text, that get inserted into the placeholders in the i18n-property in my message.properties. Therefore, i'm putting the parameters as a String array into the Flash Scope, like this:

```
//exception.getParameters returns String[]
flash.put("errorParams", exception.getParameters())
```

Now i also want to be able to use this String array as parameters for an outputFormat element, to insert them into a property like `Welcome, {0} {1}`. 
So i tried to achieve this by using *ui:repeat*:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle[flash.error]}" rendered="#{! empty flash.error}" class="invalid">
  <ui:repeat value="#{flash.errorParams}" var="_param">
    <f:param value="#{bundle[_param]}"/>
    <!-- also doesn't work: <f:param value="#{_param}"/>-->
  </ui:repeat>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Unfortunately, the param value is ignored and the placeholders of the i18n-property aren't replaced, so the rendered output is `Welcome, {0} {1}`. When using a "regular" repeater, displaying the array elements just as an outputtext, it works. So the outputFormat tag doesn't seem to support the use of a repeat as a child.
Damn, so close ;) Anyone knows a good way to do what i want, or is there any component library supporting something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that `ui:repeat` is a render-time child of `h:outputFormat` which it indeed doesn't support at all. You'd like to put multiple `f:param` elements directly as children of `h:outputFormat` during build time.

The `c:forEach` is suitable for this task. The JSTL core tags (which are already included in Facelets, so you don't need to install any extra JARs) do their job during *building* the view tree, right before it's JSF turn to *process/render* the view tree.

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
...
<h:outputFormat value="#{bundle[flash.error]}" rendered="#{! empty flash.error}" class="invalid">
  <c:forEach items="#{flash.errorParams}" var="_param">
    <f:param value="#{bundle[_param]}"/>
  </c:forEach>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: Yeah, just discovered it some days ago. I had problems with FacesMessages as they don't survive redirects (which i do often), so i'm using the Flash-Scope instead, which is an ideal replacement.

Comment: @ifischer what do you mean by "FacesMessages as they don't survive redirects " ?

Comment: @Tarik: they're request scoped.