# JSF - variable set of params based on postback

Tags: jsf, page-lifecycle, param

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264629/jsf-houtputformat-use-array-values-as-parameters), the excellent BalusC pointed out the use of <c:forEach> to get the parameters at build time.

**The Code**

I have a more complicated version of that with a variable amount of parameters (<f:param> elements) that are based on another part of the form.  The top part of the form has a DataTable of all possible "Criteria".  The bottom part has a PrimeFaces graphicImage whose content is based on the selections in those criteria, including only criteria that are used.

```
<p:dataTable var='criterion' value='#{criteria}'
    binding="#{searchBean.criteriaList}" id="#{id}">
  ... each row shows a criteria, which has a parameter name, an operator, and a value ...
  ... each row may be set or not set ...
</p:dataTable>

<p:graphicImage value="#{searchBean.lineChartImage}">
  <c:forEach var="criteriaName" items="#{searchBean.usedCriteriaKeys}">
    <f:param name="#{criteriaName}" value="#{searchBean.criteriaMap[criteriaName]}"/>
  </c:forEach>
</p:graphicImage>
```

**Background**

I know the searchBean.lineChartImage method gives me the right chart as long as the parameters are set.

The SearchBean is a RequestScope bean.

I'm using JSF 2.1, Tomcat 7.0.22, and Primefaces 2.2.1.

**The Problem**

When I select/enable a criteria (e.g. param="eventDate", operator="after", value="2011-10-01"), the parameters of graphicImage are created early in the lifecycle at tree creation time in the RestoreView phase; the set of parameters that I actually want is not updated until the UpdateModelValues phase.

Is there a way to get a set of parameters for the p:graphicImage based on the actual results of the postback itself?

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. I however don't really see a clear solution for in the view side. Your best bet is to append those parameters yourself to the property behind `#{searchBean.lineChartImage}` in the bean's action method.

```
this.lineChartImage = imageURL + "?" + toQueryString(criteriaMap);
```

with this utility method

```
public static String toQueryString(Map<String, String> params) {
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

    for (Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
        if (queryString.length() > 0) {
            queryString.append("&amp;");
        }

        queryString
            .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"))
            .append("=")
            .append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return queryString.toString();
}
```

It would have been possible if there exist a `<f:params>` which accepts a `Map<String, String>` or maybe even `Map<String, String[]>` as value.

Comment: I forgot to mention that #{searchBean.lineChartImage} is a method returning a StreamedContent object (that's a feature of p:graphicImage in Primefaces); thus the string appending doesn't work.  This is out of my sphere of knowledge, but I wonder if it would be possible to bind the GraphicImage and then add the parameters manually to the component tree during the postback.  Otherwise, I should probably create my own servlet to generate the image, and use the string concatenation method you suggested here to point to that servlet.

Comment: Hmm, binding would in theory work. But I wonder if it isn't possible to add parameters to `StreamedContent` itself? I have never used it, so I can't go in detail about that. What kind of image is it? A JFreeChart chart? Is it possible to add parameters to it programmatically?

Comment: [Primefaces Dyna Image Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf) shows an example of dynamically creating the image.  The <p:graphicImage value="..."> element renders an img, which is linked to call the method specified in the value; if the parameters are not passed on that URL, then the processing of the GET has no way of knowing what to display.  The servlet method using your build-the-query-string approach is looking more and more appealing because I'll actually be in control, not the framework.

Comment: It should be possible to move that image-creating job to a `@PostConstruct` method or a bean action method so that it isn't created directly upon construction of the bean, but only after when the request parameters are obtained by `@ManagedProperty` or submitted form data as bean's properties.